# python - tkinter command = lambda late binding issue in nested for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm trying to make multiple buttons in double for loop. I couldn't find the syntax about this problem.

```
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        b = tk.Button(new_root,command = lambda i=i : test1(i,j))
        b.place(x = (j*30), y = (i*30))
```

I understood that part using i=i to avoid late binding issue for i, but what should I do for j? the other iterator?? 
thank you so much in advance,

Comment: Do the same, eg: `lambda i=i, j=j:`...

Comment: oh yeah it worked.. thank you! it was really simple thing... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to give both variable to lambda function:

```
lambda i=i, j=j: test1(i,j)
```